# PHP: STR replace by link

Tags: php, text, hyperlink

i have this PHP chatbox.

If i would type a link in the chatbox, it would not display it as a link.

How can i use STR replace to do this?

It should respond to stuff like 'http' 'http://' '.com' '.nl' 'www' 'www.' ....

My other STR replace lines look like these:

```
$bericht = str_replace ("STRING1","STRINGREPLACEMENT1",$bericht);
```

Someone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey! Try this code (found at php.net somewhere):

```
function format_urldetect( $text )
{

  $tag = " rel=\"nofollow\"";
  //
  // First, look for strings beginning with http:// that AREN't preceded by an <a href tag
  //
  $text = preg_replace( "/(?<!<a href=(\"|'))((http|ftp|http)+(s)?:\/\/[^<>\s]+[\w])/i", "<a target=\"_new\" class=\"httplink\" href=\"\\0\"" . $tag . ">\\0</a>", $text );
  //
  // Second, look for strings with casual urls (www.something.com...) and make sure they don't have a href tag OR a http:// in front,
  // since that would have been caught in the previous step.
  //
  $text = preg_replace( "/(?<!<a href=(\"|')http:\/\/)(?<!http:\/\/)((www)\.[^<>\s]+[\w])/i", "<a target=\"_new\" class=\"httplink\" href=\"http://\\0\"" . $tag . ">\\0</a>", $te
xt );
  $text = preg_replace( "/(?<!<a href=(\"|')https:\/\/)(?<!http:\/\/)((www)\.[^<>\s]+[\w])/i", "<a target=\"_new\" class=\"httplink\" href=\"http://\\0\"" . $tag . ">\\0</a>", $t
ext );
  return $text;
}
```

Uhm, broken indentation. try this http://triop.se/code.txt

Comment: Thanks, this gets me on the way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use regex instead. look at [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg-replace)

```
$regex = '`(\s|\A)(http|https|ftp|ftps)://(.*?)(\s|\n|[,.?!](\s|\n)|$)`ism';
$replace = '$1<a href="$2://$3" target="_blank">$2://$3</a>$4'

$buffer = preg_replace($regex,$replace,$buffer);
```