# enter link to chatbox

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: STR replace by link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587480/php-str-replace-by-link)

i'm trying to make a website that has a chatbox or a shoutbox..

when i enter a link on the textarea, for example http://link.com/ and submit it, it appears just a plain text on the chatbox, how can i make it like facebook chat any other chat that when you enter a link it will display as a link with the underline that you can click.. and i don't know how to do it..

Answer (score 0):

[RegEx](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) and [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) are a good start for this:

```
$pattern = "/http:\/\/(www\.)?([^.]+\.[^.\s]+\.?[^.\s]*)/i";
$replace = "<a href='http://\\1\\2'>http://\\1\\2</a>";
$string = preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$string);
echo $string;
```

The good point here is, you can type in something like:

`Hello, look at my site http://www.google.de`

Which will be translated into:

`Hello, look at my site <a href="http://www.google.de">http://www.google.de</a>`

Comment: That regexp doesn't find URIs as defined by RFC2396. [Here's one that does](http://timezra.blogspot.se/2010/05/regex-to-validate-uris.html), but it ain't pretty.

Comment: Yes, you are right, just for showing how to do it. the one you linked would be a bit overkilled here :D

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as marked